# Is there a tool for remotely monitoring resource usage on OS X workstations?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

We have a bunch of OS X workstations and some users have complained that there isn't enough memory on them.  We'd like to monitor some resource usage stats over time to see if we should upgrade memory on all the machines or not - is there a good tool that does this?

Answer (score 2):

1 word... [SNMP](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA20884).  After SNMP is installed, there are hundreds of tools that can monitor your machines and create all sorts of pretty graphs of whatever you wish to monitor.  (cpu/ram/processes running/etc...)  I recommend something like Cacti.  It's pretty simple to get going.

Comment: Can SNMP be enabled on Mac OS X Clients?  If so, do you know if it's possible to get hardware sensor information?

Comment: First, click on the link I provided in my answer... (click on "SNMP") there is no difference between server & client when it comes to OSX anymore.  Second, you can build your own custom entries into the snmpd absolutely.  This isn't very easy, but it is doable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Ganglia](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/unix_open_source/ganglia.html) it's a great open source software, and you see all the bottlenecks per workstations. Ganglia create graphs per user, and per resource (cpu/ram/disk/etc)